# How to make a TransactionSearch call to Paypal API using Python

Tags: python, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have the necessary authentication details and I'm trying to do a TransactionSearch. I keep getting an error:
             **ACK=Failure&L_ERRORCODE0=81002&L_SHORTMESSAGE0=Unspecified%20Method&L_LONGMESSAGE0=Method%20Specified%20is%20not%20Supported&L_SEVERITYCODE0=Error**

Here is my code:

```
(timestamp, signature) = signaturegen.getAuthHeader(apiUser=settings.USERNAME, apiPass=settings.PASSWORD, accessTok=res2["token"], secTok=res2["tokenSecret"], httpMethod="POST", scriptURI="https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp")    
#the above operation is used to generate the timestamp and signature

headers = {"X-PAYPAL-AUTHORIZATION": "timestamp="+<timestamp>+",token="+<token>+",signature="+<signature>, "SUBJECT": settings.<API_USERNAME>}

data = {
"METHOD": "TransactionSearch",
"STARTDATE": "2012-01-01T05:38:48Z",
    }
req= urllib2.Request("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp", simplejson.dumps(data), headers)
res = urllib2.urlopen(req).read()
```

What i'm I doing wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Use `urllib.urlencode` instead of `simplejson.dumps` for merchant nvp APIs.

```
req= urllib2.Request("https://api-3t.sandbox.paypal.com/nvp", urllib.urlencode(data), headers)
```